# non-interference pipeline triggers between 2 azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 2 pipelines named as a.yml & b.yml. Both of them are under the folder **cci-project/xyz-lable-service/devOps/**

How can I create a following pipeline trigger

for pipeline a.yml it will be triggered by branch update **except** pipeline b.yml

for pipeline b.yml it will be only triggered by if anything updated in the b.yml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for pipeline a.yml it will be triggered by branch update except pipeline b.yml

We could use the Branches and Paths trigger like following in the `a.yml`:

```
 trigger:
   branches:
     include:
     - master
     - Dev
    
   paths:
     exclude:
     - b.yml
```

> for pipeline b.yml it will be only triggered by if anything updated in
> the b.yml file

We could only set the path trigger include the `b.yml` file in the `b.yml`:

```
 trigger:
   paths:
     include:
     - b.yml
```

You could check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) for some more details.

Hope this helps.